# Attempt to dual boot Windows 10 & Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS failed. How to fix?

Tags: dual-boot, server, windows

I am new, but have read quite a few post on this subject, but I can't find a case similar to mine.
I'm not new to Ubuntu Server 14.04, not an expert either, but I mostly manage the jobs I want done. Not so with dual booting.
I had a brand new Windows 10 installation, I prepared the SSD for dual booting even before installing Windows 10. I now have a 450MB recovery partition, a 100MB EFI system partition & a 100GB partition with Windows 10. Besides that, I have a 12GB EFI system partition where Ubuntu Server is installed & a 7,5 swap partition on that disk.
I installed Windows 10, I researched the dual booting thing & went to install Ubuntu Server, but it didn't work out as planned... Upon boot I got the GRUB menu & could choose both Windows & Ubuntu, but halfway through boot Ubuntu appeared to just sit there (Windows 10 just worked fine)...
So I went and redid the install of Ubuntu & now there's no GRUB menu, but if I set the windows partition as primary boot device (in UEFI bios) it boots in windows and if I set the ubuntu partition as primary boot device it boots Ubuntu.
How can I get the GRUB menu back & get a proper dual booting setup.
If there is any more info needed to answer my question, I'll gladly research

Answer (score 0):

Congrats on getting the dual-boot working. Reinstalling GRUB2 is a common practice to return control to the bootloader after installing an OS. Boot into Ubuntu and type the following on a terminal.

```
 sudo grub-install /dev/sdX  # Example: sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

Note that X is the drive letter you wish for GRUB to write the boot information.

For more info, see: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing

Comment: I'm having difficulties getting this to work. As in I followed the described procedure & when I restart the PC it shows the GRUB menu, I can choose either Ubuntu or Windows & they boot properly as far as I can tell, but once I try restarting the PC, I get this black screen with blinking cursor instead of the GRUB menu.

Comment: I tried running boot repair and it quits with some kind of error [grub-efi-amd64-signed purge cancelled. Please report this message to boot.repair@gmail.com] but here is the BootInfo Summary made by boot repair http://paste.ubuntu.com/12590577/
I will now go & try reboot